# Selection of records on bases of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is my query and I want the selection of Qty from those SKU which is going to expire first. Please help me how can I do this.

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1)
, SKU varchar(10)
, QtyRec int
, Expiry date
, Rec date)
DECLARE @Qty int = 20

INSERT @Data VALUES
('001A', 5 ,'2017-01-15','2015-11-14'),
('001A', 8 ,'2017-01-10','2015-11-14'),
('001A', 6 ,'2015-12-15','2015-11-15'),
('001A', 25,'2016-01-01','2015-11-16'),
('001A', 9 ,'2015-12-20','2015-11-17')

;WITH sumqty AS 
(
 SELECT *, SUM(QtyRec) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id) AS TotalQty FROM @Data
)
,takeqty AS (
SELECT *, 
CASE 
  WHEN @Qty >= TotalQty THEN QtyRec 
  ELSE @Qty - ISNULL(LAG(TotalQty) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id), 0)
END AS TakeQty
FROM sumqty
)
SELECT * FROM takeqty WHERE TakeQty > 0
```

Comment: Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef204/6/0?

Comment: Please read [ASK]. You need to include the code in the question, and not just have it on an external site. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: You really need to describe to actual problem you have. Last time it was getting data out of temp. table sorted without using order by and now... well, it's quite impossible to know.

Comment: My problem is this i want to implement data retrieval rule like.. FEFO(First expiry first out),LEFO (Last Expiry First Out), FIFO (First In First Out ) in query... I want to select the quantity from those sku who is going to expire first. This is what i want achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible outcomes depends on your question:

If you want to order result-set based on Expiry date ascending order, then Use `ORDER BY Expiry` at the end of CTEs query. Or select top expire: Use `SELECT TOP(1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Expiry) AS 'SN'` instead of `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Expiry) AS 'SN'`

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1)
, SKU varchar(10)
, QtyRec int
, Expiry date
, Rec date)
DECLARE @Qty int = 20

INSERT @Data VALUES
('001A', 5 ,'2017-01-15','2015-11-14'),
('001A', 8 ,'2017-01-10','2015-11-14'),
('001A', 6 ,'2015-12-15','2015-11-15'),
('001A', 25,'2016-01-01','2015-11-16'),
('001A', 9 ,'2015-12-20','2015-11-17');

WITH sumqty AS 
(
 SELECT *, SUM(QtyRec) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id) AS TotalQty FROM @Data
)
,takeqty AS (
SELECT *, 
CASE 
  WHEN @Qty >= TotalQty THEN QtyRec 
  ELSE @Qty - ISNULL(LAG(TotalQty) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Id), 0)
END AS TakeQty
FROM sumqty
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Expiry) AS 'SN'
    ,   SKU
    ,   QtyRec
    ,   Expiry
    ,   Rec
    ,   TotalQty
    ,   TakeQty
FROM takeqty WHERE TakeQty > 0
ORDER BY Expiry;
```